# ¿Como repetir una animación con jquery infinitas veces o cada 5 segundos?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, animated

Hola amigos soy nuevo en el mundo del jquery y estoy realizando mi portafolio web y quiero que una animación se repita infinitamente... agradecería mucho su ayuda !!!

```
$('.skillbar').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
        width: $(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, 1500);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple, usa el método nativo de `javascript` [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval), ejecutará todo lo que le pongas dentro de la función que recibe como primer párametro cada **N** milisegundos que le indiques en su segundo párametro:

```js
setInterval(function(){
  console.log('Hola, soy una animación, wii!');
}, 5000); // 5000 milisegundos = 5 segundos
```

Para tu código sería algo así:

```js
function animate(){

  $('.skillbar').each(function () {
      $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
          width: $(this).attr('data-percent')
      }, 1500);
  });
  
}

setInterval(animate, 5000);
```

Comment: no me funciono copio link de lo que quiero animar http://bizcomputers.com.co/home/paquetes-de-inversion/

Comment: @NestorLedezma Yo visualizo correctamente la animación cada 5 segundos

Comment: @joruis yo pensé que la barras lo que harían es que se vacíen y se llenen constantemente

Comment: Eso hace parte ya, de tu código, pero el interval se está ejecutando cada 5 segundos correctamente, así que prueba mejor a aceptar mi respuesta como correcta y realizar una nueva para la animación que quieres :D

Comment: tu me ayudarías con esa nueva pregunta  ? como la formulo?

Comment: Claro, no solo yo, muchas otras personas te pueden ayudar, con tu anterior comentario puedes darte a una idea de como formularla, intentar recrear todo el escenario aquí en un snippet sería lo mejor para poder ayudarte

Answer (score 2):

Una forma para que realmente estes esperando a que termine la animación para comenzar de nuevo, sería la siguiente:

### Ejecutar una animación infinitas

- Crear una función (`eg: animateSkillbar`) para ejecutar la animación
- Luego utilizar la opción [`complete`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/#animate-properties-options) ("*Una función que se llama una vez que la animación de un elemento está completa*") e indicamos que queremos ejecutar la función creada (`eg: animateSkillbar`).

Ejemplo:

```
function animateSkillbar(){
  $('.skillbar').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width: $(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, {
      duration: 1500,
      complete: animateSkillbar
    });
  });
}
```

### Ejecutar animación cada `5 segundos`:

- Utilizar la función [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout)

Ejemplo:

```
function animateSkillbar(){
  $('.skillbar').each(function () {
    $(this).find('.skillbar-bar').animate({
      width: $(this).attr('data-percent')
    }, {
      duration: 1500,
      complete: function() {
         window.setTimeout(animateSkillbar, 5000);
      }
    });
  });
}
```